# Getting OLEDB Connection error in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Developed SSIS package in SQL Data tools version 2012. 
Machine used Window 7, 64 bit OS.

I have one Sequence container which contains some DFTs.

1. Each DFT in Seq Container will get data from one table X and checks if it is already exists in main table M, if Yes move old record from main M to history H and update the new values in main table M. If No then directly insert the new records into main table M.
2. Since I am getting Connection values Dynamically, I have set Delay validation for all the Data Flow Tasks, Connection managers to True. But still i am getting below error.

> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error
>   code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft
>   SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Login
>   timeout expired". An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft
>   SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description:
>   "Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response". An
>   OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "TCP Provider: Timeout
>   error [258]. ". SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DW_Default"
>   failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method
>   call failed. History Reprojection failed validation and returned error
>   code 0xC020801C.

One or more component failed validation. There were errors during task validation.

Please Suggest. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you connect to the SQL Server through SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). I expect you will also get "Login Timeout Expired" - are you certain your connection information is correct?

Comment: Hi, I am able to connect to these DB servers now. But Since this package is scheduled to run automatically once in a day I am not sure about was there any connection issues at that particular point of time. Do you think it is because of connection issue. Because I get this issue very often, where as other packages using the same DB Server runs without any errors. Please suggest? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Here's a bunch of tests you can run _while_ this package is failing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx Are you able to do that or is it run in the middle of the night? Can you check the source SQL Serve logs to see what it's doing? it might be really busy and under resourced

Comment: I had a look around and could not find one 'handy' script to repeatedly test SQL Server connectivity anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

noticed this is a 7 years old question. answers may not help you but could help others.  I had the same issue recently.it is not a consistent error, happened once a while. The resolution is to check the target SQL server (data source in your case DW_Default) performance. In my case, the memory was starving in sql server and resolved with increasing memory on data source sql server. Someone suggests increase timeout on sql server, I didn't try that because I believe 10 seconds default setting should be enough for my case (sql servers and server where ssis running on are in same data center)
my error log is: (replaced sensitive names with xx)
Executed as user:  xx. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.5426.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  4:00:01 PM  Error: 2022-12-13 16:00:17.66     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: xx Connection manager "xx"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Login timeout expired".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unable to complete login process due to delay in login response".  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "TCP Provider: Timeout error [258]. ".  End Error  Error: 2022-12-13 16:00:17.66     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Fetch  xx List from xx ErrorLog [96]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "xx" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2022-12-13 16:00:17.66     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Fetch xx List from Web SSIS.Pipeline     Description: xx failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2022-12-13 16:00:17.66     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Fetchxx     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2022-12-13 16:00:17.66     Code: 0xC0024107     Source:xxfrom xxDescription: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  4:00:01 PM  Finished: 4:00:17 PM  Elapsed:  16.438 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).